# Condition for $f^\prime$ to be absolute integrable

Tags: pr.probability, integration

Suppose $f(x)$ is the probability density function of a random variable $X$, which means:

$$\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx = 1$$

Also suppose $f$ is continuous and differentiable.

Provide a non-trivial condition under which $\int_{a}^{b} |f^\prime(x)| dx$ exists.

$[a,b]$ maybe a compact interval (regular integral) or $[-\infty, \infty]$ (improper integral).

EDIT: a *non-trivial* condition is a condition that is satisfied by many well-known distributional families.

Comment: can you give an example where this integral does not exist?

Comment: See this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/742185/1043377).

Comment: *Provide a non-trivial condition*  Define "non-trivial".

Comment: @MingzhouLiu --- the function in the earlier post you mention is not continuous at the points $n+2^{-n}$, which is what you require in your question...

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Indeed. Then, I can not offer an example where the integral does not exist. Could you prove that the integral always exists?

Comment: Actually $|f'|$ is measurable and non-negative so the integral does exist. Maybe you mean "is finite" ?

Comment: If f is absolutely continuous then f' [exists a.e.] and is Lebesgue integrable

Comment: @PietroMajer Hi, what do you mean by "exists a.e."? Besides, as far as I know, "absolutely continuity indicates Lebesgue integrability" only holds on compact intervals.

Comment: @fedja See the EDIT.

Comment: @Mingzhou of course; if not compact add "locally"

Answer (score 2):

A sufficient condition is unimodality of $f$, namely the existence of some $c \in~]a,b[$, such that $f$ non-decreasing on $[a,c]$ and $f$ non-increasing on $[a,c]$. If this property holds, then by Fatou's lemma
\begin{eqnarray*} 
\int_a^c |f'(x)|dx 
&=& \int_a^c \lim_{h \to 0+} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}dx \\
&\le& \liminf_{h \to 0+} \int_a^c \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}dx \\
&=& \liminf_{h \to 0+} \frac{1}{h}\int_c^{c+h} f(x)dx - \frac{1}{h}\int_a^{a+h} f(x)dx \\
&=& f(c)-f(a).
\end{eqnarray*}
In a same way,
$$\int_a^c |f'(x)|dx \le f(c)-f(b).$$
The conclusion follows.

The same argument applies when $f$ has only finitely many critical points, since,  by Darboux Theorem, the sign of $f'$ remains constant between two critical points.

Comment: How about cases when the integral is an improper one? i.e., both $a$ and $b$ are infinity.

Comment: The argument given in my post still apply in this case.